# Trouble publishing .net core project in VS 2017

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I converted my .net core project to use VS 2017 last night, made some code changes/fixes, and am now trying to publish it to my server (aspnix.com) but the ftp publish is not working properly.

I filled out the publish profile with all of the pertinent info and verified the connection but when I hit publish it compiles, then just says:

```
Connecting to ftp://xxx.yyy.com/
... several lines of compiler info
MyProject -> C:\<folder path info>bin\Release\netcoreapp1.0\MyProject.dll
Web App was published successfully ftp://xxx.yyy.com/
Web App was published successfully http://www.mywebsite.com/
```

When publishing in VS2015 I would actually see the files transfering via the ftp upload but none of that shows up now.  It just says `========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========` and opens my webpage up in chrome, but no changes actually occurred.

Has anyone else run into this?  Any idea how to fix it?

Update:
I did a publish to folder and then used filezilla to ftp the entire `bin/Release/PublishedOutput` folder to my host and it sorta worked.  I mean the pages load but they are really slow and some of the css is messed up and there are some 500 errors.  At least it tells me the host can run my this kind of project but this is not a viable long term option.

Answer (score 0):

i think they didn't finish this function yet ...

[Publish Not Working in VS 2017 IDE](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24972/publish-not-working-in-vs-2017-ide.html)

[FTP publish finishs "published successfully" without copying a single file](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/34104/ftp-publish-finishs-published-successfully-without.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I ended up reverting to VS2015.  The publish to local + Filezilla approach can work but I didn't feel like messing with it.  Plus, I prefer the project.json file structure and (at least for now) VS2017 doesn't actually give me anything new that is worth updating for.